# Jenkins Windows | Build > Execute Windows Batch Command | How to move folder and files into the Root Directory / Workspace

Tags: windows, jenkins, directory, command, root

I could really need some help right now.

I want to move files (with subfolders and files in it) into the root / workspace of my current jenkins App. My other batch commands work, for example:

`move app laravel` moves the app folder and its content into the laravel folder
And i think it works without a problem because I can call the absolute folder.

but if I want to move my files "dynamically" using an relative path (move to root):
`move public/.htaccess ./` it throws an error that it coudn't find the path.

I also tried the following synonyms for the root directory, but none worked:

`..`, `$WORKSPACE`,`%WORKSPACE%`, `ws`, `workspace`, `/workspace/<appname>`, `<appname>` or `/` .. or `\` im just out of ideas by now.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it...

I researched the folder structure and found that one of my earlier trys kinda worked. It moved files into the Jenkins/workspace folder. That wasnt planned but because of that I now knew that some command must have worked!

The command that worked was `..` as the destination directory, because it is in the root directory.

So my Solution now was simple:

`move public\*.* .`